# Combine datepicker and date.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Has anyone combined the JQuery Datepicker  and Date.JS together in one control. I have found several posts alluding to this but have not found any examples of how it is done. 
I found this http://marcgrabanski.com/article/datejs-javascript-library
but then the trail goes cold. Has there been any movement on this?

Any pointers would be useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reviewing the code of the datepicker I noticed that the DateJS library is already incorporated.

```
/**
 * Version: 1.0 Alpha-1 
 * Build Date: 13-Nov-2007
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2007, Coolite Inc. (http://www.coolite.com/). All rights reserved.
 * License: Licensed under The MIT License. See license.txt and http://www.datejs.com/license/. 
 * Website: http://www.datejs.com/ or http://www.coolite.com/datejs/
 */
```

This answers part of my question. I did notice that the default locale has been supplied as en-US , it may be worth noting that if you would like to use the functionality you will need to ammend the line :

```
Date.CultureInfo={name:"en-US",englishName:"English (United States)",nativeName:"English (United States)",dayNames:["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],abbreviatedDayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],shortestDayNames:["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],firstLetterDayNames:["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"],monthNames:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],abbreviatedMonthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],amDesignator:"AM",pmDesignator:"PM",firstDayOfWeek:0,twoDigitYearMax:2029,dateElementOrder:"mdy",formatPatterns:{shortDate:"M/d/yyyy",longDate:"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",shortTime:"h:mm tt",longTime:"h:mm:ss tt",fullDateTime:"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",sortableDateTime:"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",universalSortableDateTime:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ",rfc1123:"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT",monthDay:"MMMM dd",yearMonth:"MMMM, yyyy"},regexPatterns:{jan:/^jan(uary)?/i,feb:/^feb(ruary)?/i,mar:/^mar(ch)?/i,apr:/^apr(il)?/i,may:/^may/i,jun:/^jun(e)?/i,jul:/^jul(y)?/i,aug:/^aug(ust)?/i,sep:/^sep(t(ember)?)?/i,oct:/^oct(ober)?/i,nov:/^nov(ember)?/i,dec:/^dec(ember)?/i,sun:/^su(n(day)?)?/i,mon:/^mo(n(day)?)?/i,tue:/^tu(e(s(day)?)?)?/i,wed:/^we(d(nesday)?)?/i,thu:/^th(u(r(s(day)?)?)?)?/i,fri:/^fr(i(day)?)?/i,sat:/^sa(t(urday)?)?/i,future:/^next/i,past:/^last|past|prev(ious)?/i,add:/^(\+|after|from)/i,subtract:/^(\-|before|ago)/i,yesterday:/^yesterday/i,today:/^t(oday)?/i,tomorrow:/^tomorrow/i,now:/^n(ow)?/i,millisecond:/^ms|milli(second)?s?/i,second:/^sec(ond)?s?/i,minute:/^min(ute)?s?/i,hour:/^h(ou)?rs?/i,week:/^w(ee)?k/i,month:/^m(o(nth)?s?)?/i,day:/^d(ays?)?/i,year:/^y((ea)?rs?)?/i,shortMeridian:/^(a|p)/i,longMeridian:/^(a\.?m?\.?|p\.?m?\.?)/i,timezone:/^((e(s|d)t|c(s|d)t|m(s|d)t|p(s|d)t)|((gmt)?\s*(\+|\-)\s*\d\d\d\d?)|gmt)/i,ordinalSuffix:/^\s*(st|nd|rd|th)/i,timeContext:/^\s*(\:|a|p)/i},abbreviatedTimeZoneStandard:{GMT:"-000",EST:"-0400",CST:"-0500",MST:"-0600",PST:"-0700"},abbreviatedTimeZoneDST:{GMT:"-000",EDT:"-0500",CDT:"-0600",MDT:"-0700",PDT:"-0800"}};
```

To be whatever your locale is in my case it was en-GB

```
Date.CultureInfo = { name: "en-GB", englishName: "English (United Kingdom)", nativeName: "English (United Kingdom)", dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], abbreviatedDayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], shortestDayNames: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"], firstLetterDayNames: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"], monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"], abbreviatedMonthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"], amDesignator: "AM", pmDesignator: "PM", firstDayOfWeek: 1, twoDigitYearMax: 2029, dateElementOrder: "dmy", formatPatterns: { shortDate: "dd/MM/yyyy", longDate: "dd MMMM yyyy", shortTime: "HH:mm", longTime: "HH:mm:ss", fullDateTime: "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", sortableDateTime: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", universalSortableDateTime: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", rfc1123: "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT", monthDay: "dd MMMM", yearMonth: "MMMM yyyy" }, regexPatterns: { jan: /^jan(uary)?/i, feb: /^feb(ruary)?/i, mar: /^mar(ch)?/i, apr: /^apr(il)?/i, may: /^may/i, jun: /^jun(e)?/i, jul: /^jul(y)?/i, aug: /^aug(ust)?/i, sep: /^sep(t(ember)?)?/i, oct: /^oct(ober)?/i, nov: /^nov(ember)?/i, dec: /^dec(ember)?/i, sun: /^su(n(day)?)?/i, mon: /^mo(n(day)?)?/i, tue: /^tu(e(s(day)?)?)?/i, wed: /^we(d(nesday)?)?/i, thu: /^th(u(r(s(day)?)?)?)?/i, fri: /^fr(i(day)?)?/i, sat: /^sa(t(urday)?)?/i, future: /^next/i, past: /^last|past|prev(ious)?/i, add: /^(\+|after|from)/i, subtract: /^(\-|before|ago)/i, yesterday: /^yesterday/i, today: /^t(oday)?/i, tomorrow: /^tomorrow/i, now: /^n(ow)?/i, millisecond: /^ms|milli(second)?s?/i, second: /^sec(ond)?s?/i, minute: /^min(ute)?s?/i, hour: /^h(ou)?rs?/i, week: /^w(ee)?k/i, month: /^m(o(nth)?s?)?/i, day: /^d(ays?)?/i, year: /^y((ea)?rs?)?/i, shortMeridian: /^(a|p)/i, longMeridian: /^(a\.?m?\.?|p\.?m?\.?)/i, timezone: /^((e(s|d)t|c(s|d)t|m(s|d)t|p(s|d)t)|((gmt)?\s*(\+|\-)\s*\d\d\d\d?)|gmt)/i, ordinalSuffix: /^\s*(st|nd|rd|th)/i, timeContext: /^\s*(\:|a|p)/i }, abbreviatedTimeZoneStandard: { GMT: "-000", EST: "-0400", CST: "-0500", MST: "-0600", PST: "-0700" }, abbreviatedTimeZoneDST: { GMT: "-000", EDT: "-0500", CDT: "-0600", MDT: "-0700", PDT: "-0800"} };
```

I got this from the DateJS library source and copies and pasted it in

I also found this handy bit of information by going to filament website:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_date_range_picker_with_jquery_ui/

Lesson learned from my side is that all questions are answered after a bit more research :-)

Comment: I know I'm 2+ years late, but I would love to see what you put together if you still have it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a great replacement for date.js that does not alter the Date prototype, but instead provides a wrapper for Date objects.